# Which flavor of OpenID is supported by Play

Tags: playframework, openid-connect, openid

Play 2.8 supports natively "OpenID" (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaOpenID). Can someone confirm that this "OpenID" is OpenID 2 and not OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1):

Today there is in practice only one OpenIDConnect. There is no OpenID Connect 2.

You might see OAuth2 or OAuth2.1 being mentioned and OpenID Connect is build on top of OAuth.

The old OpenID style is no longer used. So you can assume it is OpenIDConnect.

For OpenID connect, do look at this article:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/31/add-authentication-to-play-framework-with-oidc

Comment: I know there is only one OpenIDConnect. But there is also (or used to be) OpenId 1 & 2 (in addition to OAuth2). Looking at the flow described in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaOpenID, it doesn't look like any of the flow of OpenIDConnect. So I do think it is the old style OpenID, but I just wanted a confirmation from someone who knows better those techs than me.

Comment: The thing on that page looks like the old OpenID protocol. IT does talk about oauth here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaOAuth

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the answer from Tore: it is the old OpenID protocol.